# in php i m creating registration and login but its not dynamic

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

```
<?php
session_start();
if (isset($_POST["btnsubmit"]))
{
    $nm=$_POST["username"];
    $pwd=$_POST["password"];
    $conn = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "simple_login");
    // Check connection
    if ($conn->connect_error)
    {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    }

    $sql = "select * from member where username='$nm' and password='$pwd'" ;
    $result = $conn->query($sql);
    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // to add sesssion value
        $_SESSION["memid"]=$row["mem_id"];
        $_SESSION["username"]=$row["username"];
        header("location:demo2.php");
    }
} else { echo "wrong username or password" ; }
?>
```

in this i am facing designing as well as database problems and also i am facing problems in storing session variables as well

Comment: What the problem you are facing for database and designing issue?

Comment: but what is the problem you are facing? any error?

Comment: replace  $sql = "select * from member where username='$nm' and password='$pwd'" ; with  $sql = 'select * from member where username="$nm" and password="$pwd"' ;

Comment: @KishanVyas Will you please print the "$result" object, because as you write the code, session will not be stored. Because you are trying to get the data by sql query but $result would be your query object, and there is no "$row" variable. So  on that line you are getting error.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <?php
    session_start();
    if (isset($_POST["btnsubmit"]))
    {
        $nm=$_POST["username"];
        $pwd=$_POST["password"];
        $conn = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "simple_login");
        // Check connection
        if ($conn->connect_error)
        {
            die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
        }

        $sql = "select * from member where username='$nm' and password='$pwd'" ;
        $result = $conn->query($sql);
    while($row = $result->fetch_array())
      {
$row["mem_id"];
$row["username"];
}
        if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        // to add sesssion value
            $_SESSION["memid"]=$_POST["username"];
            $_SESSION["username"]=$_POST["password"];
            header("location:demo2.php");
        }
    } else { echo "wrong username or password" ; }
    ?>
```

Comment: you cannot directly get the value of the row in the if condition

Comment: sorry as i asked a silly question but still helpless as i m stuck how to start from a scratch thanks if anyone helps! and thanks for yours help!!!!

Comment: will u help me for a secure registration form with jquery,ajax and java script ! just guide me thanks !

Comment: im just a learner and learning new things i cant guide any one   if my answer is correct upvote it and make it as correct answer